# error while decoding html and farsi from hex encoding in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, hex, decoding

I have some string in hex enocoding like this:

`data =  \xd8\xa7\xdb\x8c \xd9\x84\xda\x86\xdb\x8c<br/> \xd8\xa7\xda\xaf\xd8\xb1\xda\x86\xd9\x87 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa`

It contains some Persian string and some HTML elements.

Using [ddcode.com](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=d033c6de4110499ce030446d908226b7) I convert them and get meaningful results(I'm not sure that the string is in hex!), but when I want to decode the strings by python I always get errors.

Using codec:
`codecs.decode(data,'hex',errors='ignore')`

I get

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-5246163fba41> in <module>()
----> 1 codecs.decode(data,'hex',errors='ignore')

AssertionError: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (AssertionError: )
```

Using `binascii`: `binascii.unhexlify(data)`

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-fbe8c6445b8a> in <module>()
      1 import binascii
----> 2 binascii.unhexlify(data)

ValueError: string argument should contain only ASCII characters.
```

What is your suggestion? is the string in hex? if there is some none hex in the string how can I ignore them during decoding?

Answer (score 0):

> is the string in hex?

No, it's in bytes, using a broken encoding.

```
>>> 'data  \xd8\xa7\xdb\x8c \xd9\x84\xda\x86\xdb\x8c<br/> \xd8\xa7\xda\xaf\xd8\xb1\xda\x86\xd9\x87 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'data  ای لچی<br/> اگرچه اقدامات'
```

Comment: your code works for `data` but it doesn't work for some other string!
for example: `('\\r\\n                        \\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xb5\\xd9\\x84 44 \\xd9\\xbe\\xd8\\xb3 \\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xb2 21 \\xd9\\x85\\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x87 \\r\\n                    ')`
is something wrong with the latter?
why it is broken?

Comment: That text is *further* encoded incorrectly. Decode with `unicode-escape`. `>>> '\\r\\n \\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xb5\\xd9\\x84 44 \\xd9\\xbe\\xd8\\xb3 \\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xb2 21 \\xd9\\x85\\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x87 \\r\\n '.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`
`'\r\n اصل 44 پس از 21 ماه \r\n '`

Comment: It seems that your code works perfectly!
Can you explain how it works?